# Hiding web content in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3, serverless

This is more of a theoretical question for AWS S3 website hosting.

Say I have a website hosted in S3. Obviously I want the content to be public, but I don't want people to be able to download the backend scripts, images, css by simply changing the domain url. I want to hide those folders, but if I deny GetObject access in the bucket policy for the folders the application "breaks" because it can't reach those folders.

How can I secure my content to ensure the most security for my backend when it sits in an S3 bucket?

Comment: What do you mean by "the backend scripts"? Back end code would run on a server, which it sounds like you don't have. Do you actually mean _front end_ Javascript?

Comment: If you mean client-side JavaScript and CSS then it is simply not possible to protect those, because the browser must download them to render the page.  If a browser can download them then so can anything else.  If you mean a scripting language like PHP then you must be running a server and you can partition buckets into client and server.

Comment: They are considered front-end scripts. To trigger lambda functions I use Ajax and API Gateway as a trigger on button click. As such, I have the API Gateway URL in the code. I did use CORs so that only my domain can call it but although I secured it, I'd like it hidden further so as to ensure the security of the URL.

Comment: I just feel like it is a very insecure type of architecture and practice to expose these functionalities to the user if they simply inspect the web page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the website via cloudfront with restricted access, better known as `Origin Access Identity`. This will allow cloudfront distribution access to s3 bucket.

More details can be found in the AWS Docs or https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html#private-content-creating-oai

Comment: This does not address the question being asked.  An OAI can be used as part of a strategy to restrict *direct* access to bucket contents, but only by allowing access to them via another mechanism.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is the solution. I use Route53 to route to the S3 bucket. As of right now, if they do {domain}/scripts/example.js my JavaScript is brought up as text in the browser. If a user were to do this through CloudFront, the only difference is that CloudFront is now requesting that information as opposed to the user knowing the structure and typing it into the URL. Yes if they new the S3 URL it would be exposed, but no one should be able to see my S3 url through my code right now. If you feel differently, please elaborate. I'd love to learn more about it